# Audio switching in background mode AVFoundation - objective-c

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ios4, avfoundation

I have an array of Audio objects called LocalAudio. For playing audio I use `AVAudioPlayer`. I've implemented delegate method: `audioPlayerDidFinishPlaying:`,where i put code to switch next sound in my LocalAudio array.

```
 -(void) audioPlayerDidFinishPlaying:(AVAudioPlayer *)player successfully:(BOOL)flag
 {
    [self switchTrack:nextAudioIndex];
 }
```

Audio plays in background but sound doesn't switch. So how to switch audio in background mode?
For debugging i use iPad 2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use the same logic and it is working, so something else have to be incorrect.

EDIT:
Example

```
- (void)audioPlayerDidFinishPlaying:(AVAudioPlayer *)player successfully:(BOOL)flag
{
    if (flag == NO)
        NSLog(@"Playback finished unsuccessfully");

    [player setCurrentTime:0.0];


    [backgroundMusicPlayer release];
    backgroundMusicPlayer = nil;


    if (![music isEqualToString:@"10"]) {
        [self playMusicWithKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", ([music intValue] + 1)] timesToRepeat:0];
    }
}
```

where

```
- (void) playMusicWithKey:(NSString*)theMusicKey  timesToRepeat:(NSUInteger)theTimesToRepeat {

    NSError *error;
    NSString *path = [musicLibrary objectForKey:theMusicKey];

    // Initialize the AVAudioPlayer

    if (backgroundMusicPlayer == nil) {

                backgroundMusicPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:path] error:&error];
                [backgroundMusicPlayer setDelegate: self];
                [backgroundMusicPlayer setVolume:backgroundMusicVolume];
                musicLenght = backgroundMusicPlayer.duration;
        }

    // If the backgroundMusicPlayer object is nil then there was an error
    if(!backgroundMusicPlayer) {
        NSLog(@"ERROR SoundManager: Could not play music for key '%@'", theMusicKey);
        return;
    }       

    // Set the number of times this music should repeat.  -1 means never stop until its asked to stop
    [backgroundMusicPlayer setNumberOfLoops:theTimesToRepeat];

    // Play the music
    [backgroundMusicPlayer prepareToPlay];
    [backgroundMusicPlayer play];

}
```

Comment: Yes it is, even locked and in background.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Vanya. I've also found good solution for people who using AVPlayer. Works perfect:
http://www.crocodella.com.br/2011/01/using-avplayer-to-play-background-music-from-library/